# Ошибка при отвязке Service

Tags: java, android, android-service

Есть `Activity` которое делает привязку `Service`.

```
public class MainActivity extends MvpAppCompatActivity implements ServiceConnection{

    public static final String TAG = MainActivity.class.getSimpleName();


    private WebsocketService.LocalBinder binder;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_navigation);

        /*
        * Bind websocket service
        * */
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, WebsocketService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
           /*
        * Bind websocket service
        * */
        getApplicationContext().unbindService(this);
        super.onPause();
    }



    @Override
    public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceConnected() called with: componentName = [" + componentName + "], iBinder = [" + iBinder + "]");
        binder = (WebsocketService.LocalBinder) iBinder;

        //add websocket listener
        binder.getService().addListener(s -> Log.d(TAG, "onMessage() called with: s = [" + s + "]"));
    }

    @Override
    public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
        Log.d(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected() called with: componentName = [" + componentName + "]");
        binder.closeWebsocket();
    }
}
```

При сворачивании приложения я получаю ошибку:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity
>   {org.common/org.common.ui.activity.MainActivity}:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   org.common.ui.activity.MainActivity@f7c7c68
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3976)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3916)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3890)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(Unknown Source:0)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605)
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
>                                                              Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Service not registered:
>   org.common.ui.activity.MainActivity@f7c7c68
>                                                                 at android.app.LoadedApk.forgetServiceDispatcher(LoadedApk.java:1466)
>                                                                 at android.app.ContextImpl.unbindService(ContextImpl.java:1622)
>                                                                 at android.content.ContextWrapper.unbindService(ContextWrapper.java:697)
>                                                                 at org.common.ui.activity.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:155)
>                                                                 at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:7115)
>                                                                 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1407)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivityIfNeeded(ActivityThread.java:3965)
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3942) 
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3916) 
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handlePauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3890) 
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap15(Unknown Source:0) 
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1605) 
>                                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
>                                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
>                                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
>                                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
>                                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)

Comment: может `onPause` несколько раз вызывается?

Comment: Зачем вы вызываете bind/unbind у аппликейшн контекста ( `getApplicationContext()`)? Вызывайте его прямо у активити.

Comment: @zRrr вы отчасти правы, onPause вызывается несколько раз, и проблема похоже, была в том, что я вызывал onPause несколько раз, а  bindService()  делал всего лишь раз. Я уже исправил ошибку, спасибо!

Comment: @eugeneek Делал  и так как в примере указано и так как вы говорите. Проблема была не в этом!

Comment: Так а почему у вас `onPause` несколько раз вызывается? Правильней было бы с этим разобраться.

Comment: Ну это оно и должно было вызывать его несколько раз, потому что я и экран блокировал, и приложение сворачивал, в этом плане там все адекватно было, основная моя ошибка была в том, что в первый раз когда сервис был запущен - у меня получалось его отвязать, а второй раз (когда он уже был отвязан) - падало с ошибкой, что в принципе и логично, если учесть что отвязывать уже нечего.

Answer (score 1):

Внес следующие изминения в код, после чего указаная в вопрос ошибка была устранена:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onResume() called");
    /*
    * Bind websocket service
    * */
    if (!attemptingToBind) {
        attemptingToBind = true;
        getApplicationContext().bindService(new Intent(this, WebsocketService.class), this, Context.BIND_AUTO_CREATE);
    }
    super.onResume();
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onPause() called");
       /*
    * Bind websocket service
    * */
    attemptingToBind = false;
    if (bound) {
        getApplicationContext().unbindService(this);
        bound = false;
    }
    super.onPause();
}


// SERVICE CONNECTION

private boolean attemptingToBind = false;
private boolean bound = false;

@Override
public void onServiceConnected(ComponentName componentName, IBinder iBinder) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onServiceConnected() called with: componentName = [" + componentName + "], iBinder = [" + iBinder + "]");
    attemptingToBind = false;
    bound = true;

    binder = (WebsocketService.LocalBinder) iBinder;

    //add websocket listener
    binder.getService().addListener(s -> Log.d(TAG, "onMessage() called with: s = [" + s + "]"));
}

@Override
public void onServiceDisconnected(ComponentName componentName) {
    Log.wtf(TAG, "onServiceDisconnected() called with: componentName = [" + componentName + "]");

    attemptingToBind = false;
    if (bound) {
        getApplicationContext().unbindService(this);
        bound = false;
    }
}
```